# Divisibility algorithm based questions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Please vet the solution approach, and the solutions, as I feel confused:

> 1. If $x$ is $a^3$ for some integer $a$, then what are the possible remainders of $x$ when divided by $7$?

The set of remainders(residues), let $r$ on dividing any integer by $7$ are : $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Also, to find $a^3 \pmod n$ it suffices to find $r^3 \pmod n$.

These values are: $0, 1, 1, -1\equiv 6, 1, -1\equiv 6, 6$. Or, the set:$\{ 0,1,6\}$.

> 2. If $x$ is simultaneously the square one integer, let $a$, and the cube of another integer, let $b$, (like $64 = 4^3 = 8^2$) then what are the possible remainders of $x \pmod 7$.

Need find $a^3 \pmod 7$ and $b^2 \pmod 7$, and find out which values of $a, b$ give the same residue class.

The residues of $a^3 \pmod 7$ are already given above. For $b^2 \pmod 7$ are: $0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1$, or the set: $\{0,1,2,4\}$.

The same residues, $\mod 7$ occur for residues: $0, 1$.

> 3. If $n$ is an odd integer, and $n^2 + 2n$ and $n$ have the same residue $\pmod 8$. (a) What can be the remainder on division by $8$? (b) If in addition to (a), $0 \le n \le 60$, and $n \mod 7 = 5$, then what is $n$?

(a) Residues of $n \mod 8$ for odd $n$ are: $\{1,3,5,7\}$. And of $2n \mod 8$ the residues are: $(2,6,2,6)$, and of $n^2 \mod 8$ are found by simply finding $r^2 mod 8$:$(1,1,1,1)$, or $\{1\}$. $n^2 + 2n$ have the possible residues found by adding up the corresponding values of residues for $2n + n^2 \pmod 8$: $(3,7,3,7)$, or the set: $\{3,7\}$. So, $n$ values can be $8k+3, 8k+7, \forall k \in \mathbb {Z}$. So, the remainders $\mod 8$ can be : $3, 7$.

(b) If $n \mod 7 = 5$, then $n=7l+5, \exists l \in \mathbb {Z}$. The reason $\exists$ existential quantifier is used is that there is additional condition too. The possible values of $n$ in the given range are:

a) First intersection:

i)  $n=8k+3$ : 3, 11, 19, 27, 35, 43, 51

ii) $n=7l+5$ : 5, 12, 19, 26, 33, 40, 47, 54

Hence, $n=19$.

---

a) Second intersection:

i)  $n=8k+7$ : 7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 55

ii) $n=7l+5$ : 5, 12, 19, 26, 33, 40, 47, 54

Hence, $n=47$.

So, there are two possible values of $n$ in the given set of values: $19, 47$.

---

But, for larger range of values need construct equations or again compute sets and find common members by program. I feel setting equation is difficult. I can attempt only the following for finding the common members of the two sets: $8k+3 = 7l+5$.

Comment: $5^3 \equiv (-2)^3 \equiv -1$ or $5^3\equiv 125=17*7+6\equiv 6\mod 7$.  So That should be $-1 \equiv 6$ and not $-3 \equiv 4$.  But the rest of them are good.  Note $(7-a)^3 \equiv -a^3)$ so you only have to do $0,1^2,2^2,3^3$ there rest are just the negative of those.

Comment: So it is the set $\{0,1,6\} $ or more informatively $\{0,1,-1\}$.  $4$ isn't in it.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for pointing out the error. Have corrected the next question too.

Comment: If $x \equiv a^3 \equiv b^2 \mod 7$ then $x \equiv a^3$ means $x \in \{0,1,-1\}$.  If $x \equiv b^2$ then for b = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 then $b^2 \equiv 0,1,4,9\equiv 2, 16\equiv 2,4,1,$ (note $(7-a)^2 \equiv a^2$). so $x \in \{0,1,2,4\}$  So $x \in \{0,1,-1\} \cap \{0,1,2,4\} = \{0,1\}$.  Note $64\equiv 1 \mod 7$.  If $x \equiv a^2 \equiv b^3$ then either $7|x$ or $x = 7k + 1$.

Comment: For $3a$ don't forget that $n$ is odd.  so $n\equiv 0$ is not possible.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for pointing out this fine error in question #3.

Comment: For 3a they need to be the *same* residue.  If $n \equiv \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ then $n^2 + 2n \equiv\{0,3,0,7,0,3,0,7\}$ these are only equal when $n\equiv \{0,7\}$.  (If $n \equiv 3$ then $n^2 + 2*3 \equiv 15\equiv -1 \not \equiv 3 \equiv n$.)... Oh, and *I* forgot that $n$ is odd so $n\equiv 7$ and $n^2 + 2n \equiv (-1)^2 + 2*(-1) \equiv 1-2 \equiv -1 \equiv 7 \mod 8$.  (or $49 + 14 = 63 \equiv 7 \mod 8$.)

Comment: @fleablood The residues for $n$ and $n^2 + 2n$ must be the same. This way, if the residue set elements have to be compared; then it is very tedious. Please tell how to find it beforehand without computing for each value in the residue set. Theoretically, both $3$ and $7$ occur in the two sets. I agree $19$ will give residue as $3$ for $n \mod 8$, and $7$ for $n^2 + 2n \mod 8$. But, why not able to eliminate the case for $n=3$ before-hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69594/discussion-between-jiten-and-fleablood).

Comment: Not tedious.  There are only eight to check.  But $n^2+2n= n \mod 8$ means $2^n+n\equiv 0 \mod 8$.  Obviously, $n\equiv 0,,-1$  are two solutions. You also have $n (n+1)=8k $ but as n is odd n+1 must be divisible by eight.  So n=7 is only solution.